# How can I get next month of current month is there any API for that

Tags: android

Suppose todays date 06-25 then how can I get 07-25(or how can I compare with 07-25).

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

use this Method this is simple

just add one month to current date,

```
public static Date getCurrentDatePlusMonth(int month)
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
        return newDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want add one month to current date, use

```
date.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Today date "+date.getTime());
date.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
System.out.println("Next month date "+date.getTime());
```

The output will be

```
Today date Tue Jun 25 11:33:12 IST 2013
Next month date Thu Jul 25 11:33:12 IST 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

use this Method this is simple :

```
 public static Date getPrevMonthDays() {
                Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
                if (displayedDate == null)
                    displayedDate = new Date();
                cl.setTime(displayedDate);
                cl.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                displayedDate = cl.getTime();
               return displayedDate ;

            }

            public static Date getNextMonthDays() {
                Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
                if (displayedDate == null)
                    displayedDate = new Date();
                cl.setTime(displayedDate);
                cl.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                displayedDate = cl.getTime();
                return displayedDate ;

            }
```